# Firebase firestore database, add variable to a document string name

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Let's use this example below,
I want my `window.location.href` to be the name in the database. 
But it doesn't work to assign it a name this way, is there any other way?

print screen below, if you don't understand:
http://prntscr.com/im00ji

```
    db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
    name: <==(I want to name this my current url(`window.current.href`) instead of "name") 
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set the name with `[]` notation:

```
var object = {
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
}
object[window.current.href] = window.current.href;
db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set(object)
```

Comment: How do I get this info back via 'get()' or realtime database. I know the standard procedure, but the problem is that I can't use 'window.location.href' as a child, ('doc.data().window.location.href')

Comment: Same thing: you use square bracket notation. So `doc.data()[window.location.href]`.

Comment: How do I get back the data for the "name" only. I want the url link back, not the string.